# How to Get Rid of the Shadow on Buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, button, styling

I'm trying to get rid of the border shadow (not the border itself) on this button. Apparently I can't post a picture... but here's the HTML:

```html
<input type="button" value="ok" />
```

It's like a little shadow that appears on the bottom and right sides of the button. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any border shadow in Chrome or FF.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `border` properties with CSS?

Comment: Yes, border and background are set to the same color. Nevermind, it's not really a shadow, but more like the button looks 3d. Any idea how to get rid of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `border: 0` removes any shadowy effect on chrome at least

Comment: Works on every browser I'm aware of. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting background-color to your color you want, it should remove the shadow.
This way you force the browser to render your button in a solid color.

If that still doesnt work with all browsers, make a 1x1 pixel image of the color you want and set that as background image of the button.

As j08691 says that shadow does not appear in chrome. You might also want to check out a CSS reset.

Comment: why -1? Could you at least leave a feedbacK?

Answer (score 0):

not sure what is your problem, please post image to imgur.

either style it `border-style:1px solid;` or `box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000;` will fix your problem (hopefully)

```html
fix border and shadow <input type="button" style="box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000; border-style: 1px solid;" value="ok" /><br/>
fix border <input type="button" style="border-style: 1px solid;" value="ok" /><br/>
fix shadow <input type="button" style="box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000;" value="ok" /><br/>
large border <input type="button" style="border-style: 100px solid;" value="ok" /><br/>
create shadow <input type="button" style="box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #888888;" value="ok" /><br/>
```

note that not all browser show the right border-style width

Comment: Perhaps it's not a shadow, because I tried setting box-shadow to red and nothing happened. The button looks 3d. I can't do anything with Imgur (my school blocks the website). Is there any way to get rid of the 3d-ish effect?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a border that has the same color as the button background color. If your button is white try this: `border:2px solid #fff;`. Then there will be no shadow. It is also consistent across browsers. Remember that buttons differ based on the operating system. On mac os x there isn't really a border to the defualt styling of the buttons, but in xp I would imagine that there is a shadow. Hope this helps tell me if it didn't work for you.